# Are there quantitative means of measuring nozzle wear?

Tags: nozzle, fdm, maintenance

Are there quantitative means of measuring nozzle wear? What steps do you perform to measure this? If so?

I have some digital calipers, but I don't have much confidence in the measurements taken, as it's almost impossible to ensure the nozzle aperture is entirely free of filament residue.

The context here is I've recently been trying out some carbon-fiber-infused PLA filament, but I would like to keep an eye on how much it wears the nozzle and get an idea of nozzle wear rates. I can then work out if the mechanical and aesthetic qualities of the CF filament are worthwhile.

Comment: Why are people so fixated on *does anybody*?! please, formulate it in a way that is not *I am poking with a stick at the anthill*

Comment: Are you interested in *evidence of nozzle wear*? Then look at the Olsson Ruby site, they made a quantitative test on PC filament. Are you interested in *scientific papers*? There are non. are you into *methods of measuring wear*? or *signs of nozzle wear in prints*?

Comment: Do you have a microscope which you can use to take images? Also, you would probably want to examine the nozzle in situ rather than remove it every time.

Comment: Again, *what do you look for*? A grind-up curve? An estimation how long your nozzles survive? Olsson-Ruby did a test and it a brass nozzle survives about 0.5 kg of Carbonfiber.

Comment: examle: https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/a/10886/8884 references the olsson-ruby picture.

Comment: With nozzles costing 40¢/ea or less, the additional cost of carbon fiber filament is probably around 10-15x greater than the cost of a few nozzles.

Comment: Good quality E3D nozzles for my Prusa i3 mk3s are considerably more expensive than 40c. However I'm more concerned about the time/hassle factor/risk of breaking something in the process of switching nozzles. Despite following all the instructions carefully, I managed to bend the heat break trying to free a seized nozzle, last time I attempted a nozzle swap and therefore wish to only replace nozzles when absolutely required.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on CNC Kitchen measurements,

the wear can be initially estimated by judging the overall length of the nozzle. Abrasive particles wear the nozzle very little on the channel (so the diameter doesn't change, for a while) but they wear out the outer surface in contact with the printed part, resulting in a shortening.

Of course, once the shortening gets severe, the diameter will increase because you reach the inner chamber.

Comment: And Olsson ruby got some numbers on that on their pare

Comment: @Trish I noticed after writing the answer that both 0scar and I already replied to a sister question: https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/a/10886/8884